# pyspark - concatenating columns and surround by two strings

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

**Question**: How can we concatenate the columns in the following `df` and surround each column with two strings (as shown in the `desired` output)?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([["1", "2"], ["2", None], ["3", "4"], ["4", "5"], [None, "6"]]).toDF("a", "b")
df = df.withColumn("concat_ws", concat_ws("varchar(", *[F.col(c) for c in df.columns]))
df.show()
```

**Current output**:

```
+----+----+-----------+
|   a|   b| concat_ws |
+----+----+-----------+
|   1|   2| 1varchar(2|
|   2|null|          2|
|   3|   4| 3varchar(4|
|   4|   5| 4varchar(5|
|null|   6|          6|
+----+----+-----------+
```

**Desired output**:

```
+----+----+----------------------+
|   a|   b|      concat_ws       |
+----+----+-----------           +
|   1|   2| varchar(1),varchar(2)|
|   2|null| varchar(2)           |
|   3|   4| varchar(3),varchar(4)|
|   4|   5| varchar(4),varchar(5)|
|null|   6| varchar(6)           |
+----+----+----------------------+
```

Comment: Use the when/otherwise functions in spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.otherwise.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `varchar` to each column value instead of appending in between. In that case, I would use `regex_replace` to modify the column value then `concat_ws`.

```
df = df.withColumn('concat_ws', F.concat_ws(',', *[
    F.regexp_replace(F.col(x), r'^(.*)$', 'varchar($1)') for x in df.columns
]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `concat_ws` with `","` separator and apply additional [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) clause to check if column is not `null` to wrap it with `varchar(%s)` format:

```
df = df.withColumn("concat_ws", F.concat_ws(",", *[F.when(F.col(c).isNotNull(),
                                                          F.format_string('varchar(%s)', c))
                                                   for c in df.columns]))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

---

```
+----+----+---------------------+
|a   |b   |concat_ws            |
+----+----+---------------------+
|1   |2   |varchar(1),varchar(2)|
|2   |null|varchar(2)           |
|3   |4   |varchar(3),varchar(4)|
|4   |5   |varchar(4),varchar(5)|
|null|6   |varchar(6)           |
+----+----+---------------------+
```

Comment: Your suggestion also worked. Thank you for sharing your knowledge - my upvote as you deserve it.